# Write CPP program, DFA and NFA diagram for DFA accepting string with length 5 and starting at 0 , ending at 1 input(0, 1)

Tags: c++

I am having trouble in making this program and DFA:-
Write CPP program, DFA and NFA diagram for DFA accepting string with 
length 5 and starting at 0 , ending at 1 input(0, 1).

Comment: This is not computer graphics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a CG question